# What is the regex for a phone number as (XXX) XXXXXXX

Tags: regex, validation

I wanted to validate a phone number with a format of `(123) 4567890` specifically; including everything such as exactly 3 digits inside the brackets, a single space after the closing bracket, and exactly 7 digits after the space. What would be the regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct regex would be

```
\(\d{3}\) \d{7}
```

Match `(` character literally (`(` alone would open a new group), then `{3}` times `\d`(a number), then `)` literally, then a space   followed by `{7}` times `\d`

[Working regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/9iLSqa/1)